# Itertools to break an array into subarrays

Tags: python

I have an array of strings that looks something like this

```
['a', 'b', 'c.1', 'c.2', 'c.3', 'c.4', 'd.1', 'd.2', 'd.3']
```

I want to break this into something like

```
[['a', 'b', 'c.1'], ['a', 'b', 'c.2'], ['a', 'b', 'c.3'],
 ['a', 'b', 'd.1'], ['a', 'b', 'd.2'], ['a', 'b', 'd.3'],
 ['a', 'b', 'd.4']]
```

How do I go about doing this ? My Idea was to use groupby in itertools
to get something like

```
['a', 'b', ['c.1', 'c.2', 'c.3'], ['d.1', 'd.2', 'd.3', 'd.4']]
```

and then probably something like

```
result = []
for elem in nestedList:
    if isinstance(elem, list):
        temp = []
        for elem in nestedList:
            if not isinstance(elem, list):
                temp.append(elem):
        temp.append(elem)
    result.append(temp)
```

In order to do that I would need to access the next element in groupby

```
(Something like lambda x: '.' not in x and nextelement.split('.')[0] != x)
```

How do I do that?

Comment: what is `c.1`? this is invalid syntax

Comment: `c.1` isn't a correct Python syntax. Should it be a string? What's the logic? Why should `a` and `b` be treated differently?

Comment: Are those supposed to be strings?

Comment: Yep they are strings

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Youd don't need itertools.

You can simply use list comprehensions to filter strings with `'.'` or not, and combine them again in another list comprehension:

```
data = ['a', 'b', 'c.1', 'c.2', 'c.3', 'c.4', 'd.1', 'd.2', 'd.3']

lone_letters = [x for x in data if '.' not in x]
combined_letters = [x for x in data if '.' in x]

print([lone_letters + [x] for x in combined_letters])
# [['a', 'b', 'c.1'], ['a', 'b', 'c.2'], ['a', 'b', 'c.3'], ['a', 'b', 'c.4'], ['a', 'b', 'd.1'], ['a', 'b', 'd.2'], ['a', 'b', 'd.3']]
```

Answer (score 1):

Most simple approach:

```
l = ['a', 'b', 'c.1', 'c.2', 'c.3', 'c.4', 'd.1', 'd.2', 'd.3']
result = [l[:2] + [i] for i in l[2:]]
print(result)
```

The output:

```
[['a', 'b', 'c.1'], ['a', 'b', 'c.2'], ['a', 'b', 'c.3'], ['a', 'b', 'c.4'], ['a', 'b', 'd.1'], ['a', 'b', 'd.2'], ['a', 'b', 'd.3']]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an interactive demonstration of a general approach.
First define input list:

```
>>> l = ["a", "b", "c.1", "c.2", "c.3", "c.4", "d.1", "d.2", "d.3"]
>>> l
['a', 'b', 'c.1', 'c.2', 'c.3', 'c.4', 'd.1', 'd.2', 'd.3']
```

Gather common prefix elements:

```
>>> p = [e for e in l if "." not in e]
>>> p
['a', 'b']
```

Compute rest of elements:

```
>>> r = [e for e in l if e not in p]
>>> r
['c.1', 'c.2', 'c.3', 'c.4', 'd.1', 'd.2', 'd.3']
```

Compute product of prefix with each element of the rest:

```
>>> from itertools import product
>>> [x[0] + list(x)[1:] for x in product([p],r)]
[['a', 'b', 'c.1'], ['a', 'b', 'c.2'], ['a', 'b', 'c.3'], ['a', 'b', 'c.4'],
 ['a', 'b', 'd.1'], ['a', 'b', 'd.2'], ['a', 'b', 'd.3']]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) like this:

```
my_list = ['a', 'b', 'c.1', 'c.2', 'c.3', 'c.4', 'd.1', 'd.2', 'd.3']
res = [[my_list[0], my_list[1], item] for item in my_list[2:]]
```

**Output:**

```
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>>
>>> pprint(res)
[['a', 'b', 'c.1'],
 ['a', 'b', 'c.2'],
 ['a', 'b', 'c.3'],
 ['a', 'b', 'c.4'],
 ['a', 'b', 'd.1'],
 ['a', 'b', 'd.2'],
 ['a', 'b', 'd.3']]
```